# C# Out Discard, Make Compatible With C#6

Tags: c#, compatibility, c#-6.0, out, c#-7.0

I am modifying the source of a program in order to make it support the C# 6 compiler. The source is currently compatible with C# 7 and makes use of some of the new changes to syntax in C# 7. So obviously it won't compile with a C# 6 compiler.

I have for the most part finished everything.

for example, this line (not compatible with C# 6):

```
var type = transmissionType(freqDest, freqFactor, out var bytes);
```

had to be changed to this in order to be compatible with C# 6 compiler:

```
byte[] bytes;
var type = transmissionType(freqDest, freqFactor, out bytes);
```

But I have recently come across this line (not compatible with C# 6):

```
public byte[] Receive() => Receive(out _, out _, out _);
```

and I am not quite sure how I could rewrite/change this so it would be compatible with the C# 6 compiler. The `out _` appears to be some type of discard implemented into C# since C# 7 was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C# [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) variable is basically a variable result from a function call that you know you will not use. You can just declare the variables and not use them.

```
public byte[] Receive() 
{
    get
    {
        var a, b, c;
        return Receive(out a, out b, out c);
    }
}
```